# Defining Conditional Expectation through projections for non-square integrable rvs

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

This is from Asymptotic Statistics (van der Vaart) chapter 11 (problem 4).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variable defined on the same probability space.

Define $E[X|Y]$ as the measurable function $g_0$ such that $E(X-g_0(Y))^2 \leq E(X-g(Y))^2$ for all measurable $g$. In other words, $E[X|Y]$ is the projection of $X$ onto the linear space of measurable functions of $Y$.

The above definition of $E[X|Y]$ is well defined if $X, Y$ and the space of measurable $g$ are all square integrable.

Now consider $Z \geq 0$ also defined on the same probability space, but not necessarily square integrable. Define $E[Z|Y] = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} E[\min(M,Z)|Y]$

Show that this limit is well defined (exists almost surely) and that the definition coincides with the previous one of $E[Z] < \infty$.

**What I've tried**

Rewriting the expression above:
$$E[Z|Y] = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} E[\min(M,Z)|Y] = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} E[Z|Y]P(X\leq M | Y) + MP(X>M|Y)$$

But it's not clear to me that this limit exists almost surely since $E[Z|Y]$ is not well defined.
For the second part I want to show that this expression minimizes $E(Z-g(Y))^2$ for all measurable $g$ which is straightforward if $E[Z|Y]$ is well defined since in that case $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} E[Z|Y]P(X\leq M | Y) + MP(X>M|Y) = E[Z|Y]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : show that, if $X, X'$ are square integrable random variables such that $X \leq X'$ almost surely, then $E[X | Y] \leq E[X' | Y]$ almost surely.

Comment: Are you suggesting to identify a sequence approaching $Z$ from below and then apply dominated convergence? I have been trying to show that $min(Z,M)$ is square integrable for all M (since my definition of conditional expectation requires square integrability), but maybe I'm missing something and showing integrability is enough?

Comment: I see, $\min(Z, M)$ IS square integrable for all $M$.